# How to store changes history data in Oracle and handle the non-changed values

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

Hey guys I have one table called Users:
[image]

Then I have another table holding the changes, made to the above table, called Users_History_Changes:
[image]

I know I need trigger, which fires, when one table is updated and inserts values in Users_History_Changes table. But here is the thing I can't do. When a log is made in Users_History_Changes table, and only Last_Name is updated, other fields must remain empty. Then, the First_Name is changed, so the table shows only that. At the end we change the Age, and the User, with ID = 1, becomes **from** 'Raul Peres, 25' **to** 'Pedro Felipes, 30'. Time_Stamp is when the change is made.

Comment: What do you expect to see if two column values are changed by the same update statement? One history row with both new column values, or two history rows with one column populated in each? What about if an update statement says it's updating a column but the old and new values are actually the same? (Not relevant, but why are you storing *age*, which goes stale; rather than storing date of birth and calculating the age as needed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test whether each value has changed as part of the insert into the history table:

```
create trigger users_trigger
before insert or update on users
for each row
begin
  insert into users_history_changes (id, first_name, last_name, age, timestamp_changes)
  values (:new.id,
    case when :old.first_name is null or :new.first_name != :old.first_name then :new.first_name end,
    case when :old.last_name is null or :new.last_name != :old.last_name then :new.last_name end,
    case when :old.age is null or :new.age != :old.age then :new.age end,
    systimestamp);
end;
/
```

It probably isn't useful to check if a value has changed *to* null, since that wouldn't be a very helpful history record, so I've only checked *from* null. And even those tests can/should be expanded to cover edge cases, e.g. to check that *something* has actually changed.

Anyway, with the following statements:

```
insert into users
select 1, 'Raul', 'Peres', 25 from dual
union all select 2, 'Francis', 'Lotters', 40 from dual
union all select 3, 'Maria', 'Lopez', 39 from dual;

update users set last_name = 'Felipes' where id = 1;
update users set first_name = 'Pedro' where id = 1;
update users set age = 30 where id = 1;

update users set first_name = 'Maria', last_name = 'Sanchez', age = 40 where id = 3;
```

the history table ends up with:

```
        ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME         AGE TIMESTAMP_CHANGES           
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------
         1 Raul       Peres              25 19-JUN-19 20.02.33.470409000
         2 Francis    Lotters            40 19-JUN-19 20.02.33.473139000
         3 Maria      Lopez              39 19-JUN-19 20.02.33.473183000
         1            Felipes               19-JUN-19 20.02.33.548101000
         1 Pedro                            19-JUN-19 20.02.33.594305000
         1                               30 19-JUN-19 20.02.33.640293000
         3            Sanchez            40 19-JUN-19 20.02.33.688710000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70a128ba21278c83c4b66debc63276c2)

Alternatively, if you want one row per changed value, you could use the `updating` clause:

```
create trigger users_trigger
before insert or update on users
for each row
begin
  if inserting then
    insert into users_history_changes (id, first_name, last_name, age, timestamp_changes)
    values (:new.id, :new.first_name, :new.last_name, :new.age, systimestamp);
  end if;

  if updating ('FIRST_NAME') then
    insert into users_history_changes (id, first_name, timestamp_changes)
    values (:new.id, :new.first_name, systimestamp);
  end if;
  if updating ('LAST_NAME') then
    insert into users_history_changes (id, last_name, timestamp_changes)
    values (:new.id, :new.last_name, systimestamp);
  end if;
  if updating ('AGE') then
    insert into users_history_changes (id, age, timestamp_changes)
    values (:new.id, :new.age, systimestamp);
  end if;
end;
/
```

but that will generate a row for values that are 'changed' to the same value, unless you add further logic to check for actual changes - the `updating()` check is that the update statement included the column in its `set` list. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9fc6ce375fa7c3206e19f267604e8f85)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first solution is what I am searching for. This history table is made that way (with nulls), so that the changes can stand out easily. That was the task. Again this community is amazing it helps new learners so much. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare new and old values for update logging

```
create or replace trigger trg_users on users
after insert or update 
for each row
declare
  v_dml_type varchar2(1);

  procedure pr_upd_log( i_dml_type varchar2, i_col_name varchar2, 
                        i_old_val  varchar2, i_new_val  varchar2 ) is
  begin
    insert into Users_History_Changes( dml_type, col_name, old_val, new_val )
     values( i_dml_type, i_col_name, i_old_val, i_new_val );
  end;
begin

  if updating then v_dml_type := 'U';
  elsif inserting then v_dml_type := 'I'; end if; 

  if ( nvl(:old.user_id,-987) != nvl(:new.user_id,-987) ) then     
     pr_upd_log(v_dml_type,'user_id',to_char(:old.user_id),to_char(:new.user_id));
  end if;

  if ( nvl(:old.age,-987) != nvl(:new.age,-987) ) then     
     pr_upd_log(v_dml_type,'age',to_char(:old.age),to_char(:new.age));
  end if;

  if ( nvl(:old.first_name,'NuLLxYZ') != nvl(:new.first_name,'NuLLxYZ') ) then     
     pr_upd_log(v_dml_type,'first_name',:old.first_name,:new.first_name);
  end if;

  if ( nvl(:old.last_name,'NuLLxYZ') != nvl(:new.last_name,'NuLLxYZ') ) then     
     pr_upd_log(v_dml_type,'last_name',:old.last_name,:new.last_name);
  end if;     
  -- for v_dml_type = 'I', use your former way
end;
```

Comment: That's assuming a different history table layout than that shown in the question. Quite possibly better, of course, if the OP isn't forced to use the original, but a substantial change... (I'm also not a fan of using `nvl` with magic values, rather than handling to/from null explicitly; but that's a different issue *8-)

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole I can say I trust on my English but indeed, it was hard to understand from the question :)

Comment: @AlexPoole the age is totally irrelevant here, it's just a demo (test) table made quickly. To answer your first question: there will be two history rows. The second question is actually shown - the new value is empty (null) if no changes are made, the trigger won't fire. And unfortunately it's a request to be like that.
P.S Really sorry for that, my English is nice, but my explanations are idiotic.